# Does Python always use UTF-8 when reading from or writing to a file? (Open function with only file and mode args.)

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the impression, that reading from and writing to a file always uses UTF-8.
I tried to find a counter-example by using a different encoding for the script, but did not find one.

My example uses the Yen-Symbol, whose encoding in UTF-8 is `C2 A5`.
`'¥'.encode('utf-8') == b'\xc2\xa5'`

Assume a file *yen.txt*, that contains the two bytes `C2 A5`.
Are there any circumstances, under which the following code could fail?

```py
with open('yen.txt', 'r') as f:
    assert f.read() == '¥'
```

Or could the following code ever produce a text file, that does not contain the bytes `C2 A5`?

```py
with open('yen.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('¥')
```

By "circumstances" I mean the encoding of the script, or some setting of the operating system.

Assume, that the script uses some encoding, that allows the Yen-Symbol.
(Otherwise it would be equivalent to a question mark.)

I tried the write script with `# coding: cp437`, and the result was just the same.
I wondered, if the text file might instead contain only the byte `9D`,
because that is the Yen symbol's code point in [CP 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).
`'¥'.encode('cp437') == b'\x9d'`

BTW, I uploaded the modified script [on GitHub](https://github.com/entenschule/examples_py/blob/main/a001_misc/b007_encoding/cp_437/write_yen.py), and somehow the Yen-Symbol disappeared.
Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You can use the `encoding` argument to `open()` to specify the encoding. It defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: generally I prefer to open like this:

`open('yen.txt', 'rb')` 

instead of

`open('yen.txt', 'r')` 

especially when dealing with unknown data. Because if you open a file in `utf-8` encoding it may fail to open it cause of special characters that cannot be decoded in utf-8 format

Comment: "somehow the Yen-Symbol disappeared" If you look at the raw file you can see its there but the frontend just doesn't know how to parse it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/entenschule/examples_py/main/a001_misc/b007_encoding/cp_437/write_yen.py

Comment: Always specify the encoding explicitly for text mode.  It does **not** always default to UTF-8.  See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).  FYI @Barmar

Comment: The documentation says, that it uses `locale.getencoding()`. For me that does not work. (`AttributeError: module 'locale' has no attribute 'getencoding'`) But `locale.getpreferredencoding()` works, and returns "UTF-8".

Answer (score -1):

As Mark Tolonen pointed out, there is not really a default for the encoding.

In the comments of the `open` function it states the following:

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform
> dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the
> current locale encoding.
> (For reading and writing raw bytes use binary
> mode and leave encoding unspecified.)

On Linux and Mac the preferred encoding is likely `'UTF-8'`, on Windows it might be `'cp1252'`.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding(True)
'UTF-8'
```

Comment: Are you sure about that last sentence? The platform default encoding is UTF-8 is almost all modern unix-like OS (including Linux, Mac OS X and Android) but in Windows specifically it is often a different encoding (don't know about Python specifically, but Java faces the same questions). This answer looks like a classical case of "it works on my machine".

Comment: You are right. On Windows it is `'cp1252'`. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (So I suppose on Windows the "¥" should be saved as A5, if no encoding is specified.)

Comment: Even that answer is incomplete. On Windows it depends on the locale that's configured. The sane thing is to not assume anything about the return value of that function. If you want UTF-8, specify that. If you want the platform default encoding then explicitly get that (or don't provide an encoding and let it be used by default).